# Conditional formatting based on another cell's value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Fairly basic question but I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is!

I am looking to use conditional formatting to colour a figure red or green depending on whether it is under or over he target which is set in a cell. There is the possibility of the target changing so I am keen to not include the target figure in the conditional formatting iteself.

In the below example I have the conditional formatting set to show in columns F-W if the figure is less than the figure in E change to green.
In the highlighted (2nd set of data) you can see that column L, U & W are all less yet they are not green and that column G & J are more than yet they have turned green!

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REeXA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use a multiple cell range in "Apply to range" and want to reference a single cell in "Format rules", you usually want to use absolute references for column, row or both.

In your case you must use =$E5 instead of =E5

Comment: So simple! I should have known that. Thank you so much